# How to style React component with TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS in a React Project. I'm able to style normal HTML elements by passing TailwindCSS utility classes in the className attribute but this doesn't work when I pass the utility classes inside a components className attribute like this:

```
<Dropdown className="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6"/>
```

Dropdown is a React component imported into another component.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Import the tailwind css in global css file

Comment: The CSS file that Tailwind generates is already imported in the `index.js` of my React project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `<Dropdown/>` is your custom made component you probaly forgot to include in on the div inside your component definition,

you can rename "className" to `customclass` and apply it inside your component definition.

so with that your code would look like

```
<Dropdown customclasses="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6"/>
```

and your component definition,

```
const Dropdown = ({ customclasses, ...otherProps }) => <div className={customclasses}></div>
```

or if you dont want to change className you can spread the `...otherProps` directly on the `div`

```
const Dropdown = ({ yourprop, yourprop , ...otherProps }) => <div {...otherProps}></div>
```

Comment: How come it doesn't need to be passed as prop in Vue.js?